# How to rename files based on an XML content tag?

Tags: xml, windows, batch-file, rename

I am new to batch script writing and need to some help. I have a folder which has several subfolders with files as listed in below structure:

- **FOLDER 0001**

  - 0001.a00
  - 0001.a01
  - 0001.a02
  - 0001.a03
  - `annotations.xml`
- **FOLDER 0002**

  - 0001.a00
  - 0001.a01
  - 0001.a02
  - 0001.a03
  - 0002.b00
  - 0002.b01
  - 0002.b02
  - 0002.b03
  - `annotations.xml`
- **FOLDER 0003**

  - 0001.a00
  - 0001.a01
  - 0001.a02
  - 0001.a03
  - `annotations.xml`

Each folder has `annotations.xml`. This file has various XML tags.

I wish to extract the first two details between `a1` tag with the attribute value `New` and rename (or append) the files `*.[a-z][0-9][0-9]` such as `*.a00`, `*.a01`, `*.b01`, `*.b02`, etc.

```
<a1 L="New" T="xxx" etc..>ABC9876, 20200115-1630, 20200115-1730</a1>
```

I want to rename the files to:

- ABC9876.20200115-1630.a00
- ABC9876.20200115-1630.a01
- ABC9876.20200115-1630.a02

I have used the following script:

```
call xpath.bat "annotations.xml" "//a1" >> renamed.txt
```

The created file `renamed.txt` contains:

```
ABC9876, 20200115-1630, 20200115-1730*
```

I do not know how to move on with the rename, including looping all the folders and skipping those that were already done. I would be glad if I can get some ideas and assistance.

Further I tried the following:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=," %%a in (renamed.txt) do (
    echo ****************
    echo %%a echo %%b
    echo ****************
    set "new=%%a.%%b"
    set new=!new: =!
    echo !new!
    ren 0004.a03 !new!.mp3
)
pause
```

I am able to rename only one file, but I do not know how to rename all the files while keeping their existing extensions. In the above example I tried to rename one into `mp3`.

Comment: Use the command parenthesized in a `for /f` loop, or read the `renamed txt` as the parenthesized command within a `for /f` loop. Open up a Command Prompt window and enter `for /?` to learn how to best use the command and it's options.

Comment: I would advise you to pick a scripting language that can read and write xml files with a native method.

Answer (score 0):

This task could be done depending on XML file content with a batch file containing a single command line with four **FOR** loops with batch file stored in directory containing the folders with the files to rename and the XML files `annotations.xml`.

```
@for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "%~dp0annotations.xml" /A-D /B /S 2^>nul') do for /F "tokens=2 delims=<>" %%J in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R /C:"<[^<>]*=\"New\" [^<>]*>.*,.*," "%%I"') do for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=, " %%K in ("%%J") do for /F "delims=" %%O in ('dir "%%~dpI" /A-D /B ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R "^[0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789]\.[a-z][0123456789][0123456789]$"') do ren "%%~dpI%%O" "%%K.%%L%%~xO"
```

Better readable is the following multi-line variant:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "%~dp0annotations.xml" /A-D /B /S 2^>nul') do (
    for /F "tokens=2 delims=<>" %%J in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R /C:"<[^<>]*=\"New\" [^<>]*>.*,.*," "%%I"') do (
        for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=, " %%K in ("%%J") do (
            for /F "delims=" %%O in ('dir "%%~dpI" /A-D /B ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R "^[0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789]\.[a-z][0123456789][0123456789]$"') do (
                echo ren "%%~dpI%%O" "%%K.%%L%%~xO"
            )
        )
    )
)
pause
```

**Note:** There is the command `echo` left to command `ren` in above code to just output the file renaming command instead of executing the rename command. It is recommended to run this multi-line batch file first to verify if the XML files are really correct processed and so the new file name is built right.

---

The first **FOR** executes in background one more command process with `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line between `'` appended as additional arguments. So executed is with Windows installed into `C:\Windows`:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c dir "C:\batch file directory\annotations.xml" /A-D /B /S 2>nul
```

**DIR** executed by separate command process in background searches

- in batch file directory and all its subdirectories because of option `/S`
- for just files because of option `/A-D` (attribute not directory)
- with file name `annotations.xml` and
- outputs in bare format just the found file names because of option `/B` with full path because of option `/S` to handle **STDOUT** (standard output) of background command process.

It is possible that **DIR** cannot find any file matching these criteria. In this case an error message would be output by **DIR** to handle **STDERR** (standard error) which is suppressed by redirecting it to device **NUL**.

Read the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

**FOR** captures the output to handle **STDOUT** of started background command process and processes this output line by line after started `cmd.exe` closed itself after finishing execution of **DIR**.

Empty lines are skipped by default by **FOR**, but there are no empty lines in this case.

**FOR** would split up each non-empty line by default into substrings using normal space and horizontal tab as string delimiters and would assign just the first space/tab separated string to the specified loop variable. This line splitting behavior is not wanted here because of the path to file `annotations.xml` could contain one or more spaces. For that reason the option `delims=` is used to define an empty list of string delimiters which disables line splitting behavior.

**FOR** would ignore also the lines on which first substring, being the entire line in this case, starts with default end of line character `;`. But a full qualified file name as output by **DIR** cannot start with a semicolon. The full path of a file starts always either with a drive letter or a backslash in case of a UNC path. So no line is ignored by **FOR** in this case.

The first **FOR** iterates over all `annotations.xml` found in directory of the batch file and its subdirectories.

---

The second **FOR** runs again in background one more command process to execute **FINDSTR** with a case-sensitive regular expression on current `annotations.xml` to find the line containing the string `="New"` somewhere within a tag with at least two comma separated strings in value of this XML element.

The found line output by **FINDSTR** is captured by **FOR** and processed with splitting the line up into substrings using the angle brackets as string delimiters because of option `delims=<>`. Just the second angle bracket delimited string being the value of the XML element found by **FINDSTR** is assigned to specified loop variable `J` because of `tokens=2`.

---

The third **FOR** processes the value **string** of the XML element by splitting it up using comma and normal space as string delimiters as specified with `delims=,` . The first substring is assigned to specified loop variable `K` and because of `tokens=1,2` the second comma/space separated substring is assigned to next loop variable according to [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) which is the loop variable `L`.

---

The fourth **FOR** runs **DIR** in a separate command process to find all files in directory of current `annotations.xml`. The output is additionally filtered with **FINDSTR** to output finally to **STDOUT** of background command process just those file names without file path of which name is exactly four digits and the file extension starts case-insensitive with an ASCII letter and has exactly two digits next. This filtering makes it possible to run the batch file multiple times on same directory tree with avoiding to rename files which were renamed already by a previous batch file execution.

The fourth **FOR** processes the file names without file path one by one and runs the rename command with the wanted new name respectively outputs the rename command line.

---

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains `%~dp0` ... drive and path of argument 0 which is the currently processed batch file, i.e. full path of batch file always ending with a backslash.
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `pause /?`
- `ren /?`

Comment: Thanks a lot Mofi, I will check it and revert back